# how to change shape of background of active link in nav of twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap at my web site and using Nav(Basic pills) as a navigation.

When I click on list menu or hover effect the default behaviour is to show background's shape  is rectangle.

Now my problem is I want to change that shape into my own customize shape.
Please suggest me the right way to do this.

Default shape is

[image]

and shape that I want is like

[image]

Comment: What is the menu you are talking about ? Navbar ? or dropdown menu ?

Comment: I am talking about just Navs(Basic pills), and I want to give shape of "D".

Comment: In that case you might use something like CSS sprites and declare them inside the `nav-pills` class

Comment: @uDaY: will u please elaborate??

Comment: @RupeshNerkar, to define your own custom shape you might use images and make this css rule `background-image: url(..your image);` and place it inside the `nav-pills` class. That way you can have diff shapes. see `CSS-Sprites` tutorial and you will understand. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some CSS that will give you a pill that looks like this:

[image]

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a {
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.nav-pills > li.active > a::after {
   border-top: 15px inset transparent;
   border-bottom: 15px inset transparent;
   border-left: 20px solid #08C;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
}
```

You'll probably need to experiment with it a bit but that should give you the idea.

Comment: I also want to add this shape to hover effect,I am trying put this css into following code but not working .                         .nav > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:rgb(20,89,83);
}

Comment: Just define the exact same style rules but for the hover pseudo class. The selectors would be .nav-pills > li > a:hover and .nav-pills > li > a:hover::after